# Intalling Microsoft.Net.Test.Sdk did not fix "Unable to findtesthost.dll. Please publish your test project and retry." - Anything else I could do?

Tags: c#, nunit

**UPDATE: I didn't realize that I was using Class Library (.NET Standard) instead of Class Library (.NET Framework) or that the two are different to be honest. I'm very new with C#. So when I changed to .NET Framework from .NET Standard, my code started working properly.**

I want to create a UI automation framework using C# and Selenium and I followed some tutorials online on how to do this. I installed the following using NuGet Manager in Visual Studio:

1. Selenium.Webdriver
2. NUnit
3. NUnit3TestAdapter

I proceeded to create a very simple test:

```
[Test]
public void SampleTest()
{
    IWebdriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://sample.com");
}
```

After building the solution, I ran the test and got this error:

**Unable to find ....\testhost.dll. Please publish your test project and retry.**

I searched for a solution and many people solved it by installing **Microsoft.Net.Test.Sdk** so I did the same but the issue still exists.

Anything else I can try?

Here are are my project references:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
   <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.12.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="3.13.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Selenium.WebDriver" Version="3.141.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you ever figure this out?  Which online tutorial were you following? was is this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vTWV1x1lg6Q    ? I am following this tutorial and arriving at the same issue as you. It looks like all you might have to do is install the following nuget pachage to your project, "Microsof.TestPlatform.TestHost"

Comment: @Fractal I didn't realize that I was using Class Library (.NET Standard) instead of Class Library (.NET Framework) or that the two are different to be honest. I'm very new with C#. So when I changed to .NET Framework from .NET Standard, my code started working properly. I was following this tutorial. https://www.guru99.com/selenium-csharp-tutorial.html

Comment: okay, that is good to know. Thanks R. Lecc

Comment: While your update containing a solution in your question is nice, it would be nice to, at least, include your solution in an answer as well, so that other people could benefit from more easily seeing the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Got this error, when trying to debug a unit test. Below are the steps I tried.
**Step 1:** Installed Microsof.TestPlatform.TestHost and tried to run the test but no luck.
**Step 2:** Changed Target framework from .NET Core 2.0 to 2.1 and tried to run the test but no luck.
**Step 3:** Closed and opened VS2017 and tried to run. Yay!!! it worked :-)
Never miss to try the last step ;-)
Hope this helps someone like me.